# How to create a paypal payment with a custom amount?

Tags: python, paypal

I would like to integrate python's paypal sdk into my project so that users can pay however much they choose. The current method requires a fixed price, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/create-process-order/

However I want the user to be able to choose how much they want to send.

Comment: How about letting the user choose the amount of money before sending the payment request to paypal? Since you provided no code there is not much more to say.

Answer (score 0):

You linked to a server integration document, which is also for a deprecated API.

Do you want to create the order on the server side, or not? If yes, sending the amount from the client to the server that executes the orders API call is work you will need to do.

Begin your integration with the current v2/checkout/orders API by making two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). When a capture response is successful, store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) before sending your return JSON.

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Since your question was specific to setting a custom amount, you should probably add a JSON body to the createOrder's fetch call, to send the amount you want to your server.

---

For a simple client-side integration that uses no server-side API calls, see [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) and
set the createOrder purchase units `value:` with some function or variable that gets the value you want. For instance:

```js
value: document.getElementById(...).value
```

If you are not a programmer, you can even generate such a button for a custom amount via https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart